# Spring Boot Log4j2 configuration issue with log size maintenance

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, log4j2

I have a spring boot application and using log4j2 to generate console and persists logs in a centos linux.

I wanted to maintain only **5mb** of log files in archive.

But the problem is, my archived log files are 5mb in total. but my main console log which is saving in the main log file i.e wc-notification.out is going beyond 1mb.

**so my disk gets full and it causes an issue.**

**The brute force method solution is:**
whenever restarting(hard stop and start) my spring boot application, the log is cleared in from wc-notification.out.

my log4j2 configuration xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO" monitorInterval="30">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">
            [ %d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss a} ] - [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
        </Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="FileAppender" fileName="/home/ec2-user/apps/wc-notification-service/wc-notification.out"
                     filePattern="/home/ec2-user/apps/wc-notification-service/archives_test/wc-notification.out-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
                <Delete basePath="logs" maxDepth="1">
                    <IfFileName glob="wc-notification.out-*.log" />
                    <IfLastModified age="1m" />
                </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <!--<AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" /> -->
            <AppenderRef ref="FileAppender" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

somehow, the files are in range of 1mb, and the roll strategy is working, it is deleting the file

**but, my disk space is still occupied with the space. what can be the reason?**

Comment: Please, can you review your question and clarify how are you configuring log4j2? You mention `logfile.log`, but your configuration does not mention anything related with that file name. Is the provided xml file the only configuration which is in place? So, you are overwriting the spring-boot logging mechanism? Exactly, how much space do you have for your logs?

Comment: 5 gb of space is available. yes it is the only provided xml file which is in place. yes im override spring boot logging mechanism.

Comment: Thank you very much Sriram. I posted a possible solution. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are providing your own `log4j2.xml` configuration file, you are overwriting the Spring Boot default logging configuration, and it is safe to assume that it will be configuration used by Log4j2.

Your configuration is almost correct. If you want to achieve the desired behavior, I would suggest you the following changes:

- Be aware that you are pointing your `Delete` action `basePath` to the wrong location, it should point to the directory in which your logs are stored.
- The `IfFileName` `glob` pattern is wrong as well, it should match your logs filenames.
- Finally, your are using the `IfLastModified` condition. As its name implies, this condition has to do with the last modification date of the logs files, not with their size. Please, consider to use instead `IfAccumulatedFileSize` (or maybe `IfAccumulatedFileCount`). See the [relevant documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#DeleteIfAccumulatedFileSize).

For these reasons, your logs are not being deleted correctly and the disk space occupied is greater than the desired amount. Without deletion, your log files are being rotated every `1 MB` as configured by your `SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy`, and will keep until the value of the `max` attribute of `DefaultRolloverStrategy`, `7` by default, is reached, and always, plus the amount of your current log file.

In summary, please, try a configuration like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO" monitorInterval="30">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="LOG_PATTERN">
            [ %d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss a} ] - [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
        </Property>
    </Properties>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="ConsoleAppender" target="SYSTEM_OUT" follow="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${LOG_PATTERN}"/>
        </Console>
        <RollingFile name="FileAppender" fileName="/home/ec2-user/apps/wc-notification-service/wc-notification.out"
                     filePattern="/home/ec2-user/apps/wc-notification-service/wc-notification.out-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}-%i">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>${LOG_PATTERN}</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="1MB" />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
                <Delete basePath="/home/ec2-user/apps/wc-notification-service">
                    <IfFileName glob="wc-notification.out-*" />
                    <IfAccumulatedFileSize exceeds="5 MB" />
                </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingFile>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="info">
            <!--<AppenderRef ref="ConsoleAppender" /> -->
            <AppenderRef ref="FileAppender" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

The solution relies in storing all your logs in the same location. It will affect your `RollingFile` `filePattern` attribute.

Please, be careful with the delete action, it can delete not only your log files, but all that matches your `glob` pattern.

In addition, although maybe irrelevant fo your use case, be aware that if the `filePattern` of your archive files ends with ".gz", ".zip", ".bz2", among others, the resulting archive will be compressed using the compression scheme that matches the suffix, which can allow you to store more archives for the same space if required.

For your comments, it seems you encountered a problem when using large file sizes: please, see this [bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2501), I think that clearly describes your problem.

My best advice will be to reduce the size of the logs files to one that it is properly working, or try a more recent version of the library.

I am aware that you are using Spring Boot to manage your dependencies:
please, verify your maven tree and see the actual version library you are using and change it if necessary.

Comment: @Sriram Arvind Lakshmanakumar Were you able to test the proposed configuration? Did it worked properly? Is that what you need?

Comment: im still testing it.. the size base tigger is not happening.. it is not splitting the file. the main file is just growing.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. That is very strange Sriram. I tested your configuration, just modifying the file size to rotate every 1 Kb, and adjusting the rest of parameters as appropriate, and it works properly. Please, can you try the same? I mean, use something like [this](https://pastebin.com/G41EykR7). For reference, these are my dependencies:```<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.0</version>
        </dependency>```

Comment: And: ```<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.14.0</version>
        </dependency>```. Please, verify that you are using a recent version of the library. In addition, please, instead of using such large files, although Log4j will try to optimize the writes, it is advisable to use smaller files, for performance.

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
  </dependency> im using this

Comment: for 1kb the configuration is working fine, i making it 5mb and checking.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230717/discussion-between-sriram-arvind-lakshmanakumar-and-jccampanero).

Comment: @SriramArvindLakshmanakumar I updated the answer and provide more information in the chat. I hope it helps.

Comment: your answer is perfect.. but somehow my disk is still occupying space.

Comment: Thank you very much @SriramArvindLakshmanakumar. I am sorry to hear that the disk is still occupying space. Probably the best approach will be to follow and comment the bug in the apache jira site if possible and, as a workaround, try to use smaller log files for the moment. Please, do not hesitate to contact me if you think I can be of any help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to leverage the DeleteAction of the RollingFileAppender. I would recommend taking a look at the [documentation](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#Log_Archive_Retention_Policy:_Delete_on_Rollover) as there are a lot of good examples.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your behavior is as follows: look at your parameters

```
appender.gateway.policies.size.size=1MB
appender.gateway.strategy.type = DefaultRolloverStrategy
appender.gateway.strategy.max = 5
```

What you are asking here is log file should be allowed to grow up to 1M. Once it reaches 1M size it is copied to file **logfile.log-1** and a new file **logfile.log** is created. As the files get produced you required that you want to keep only 5 last files. The older files get deleted automatically. So it looks like the behavior is exactly as you configured. What you can do is to configure to keep more than 5 files back and possibly in a different folder where you have sufficient space.

Comment: my logger is doing exactly what it is told to do. but still the logs are in my disk space somehow. whenever i restart the spring boot application, the disk space gets cleared.

Answer (score 0):

Just for information to people who are facing similar issue, i just changing my logging mechanism to **logback**. it works like an charm and have no issue.

the reference link which i used: [spring boot with logback](https://springframework.guru/using-logback-spring-boot/)